# Minecraft crashing on Mac OS with Java 8 - any fixes?

Tags: macos, java, games

When I load or start a new game on Minecraft it crashes. It only happened after I installed Java 8.

```
Minecraft Version: 1.7.10
Operating System: Mac OS X (x86_64) version 10.9.4
Java Version: 1.6.0_65, Apple Inc.
```

The interesting thing is this started after install Java 8 that I downloaded from Oracle.
Any tips for fixing this?

The error says:
Description: Unexpected error

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.nio.Buffer.checkIndex(Buffer.java:512)
    at java.nio.DirectIntBufferU.get(DirectIntBufferU.java:248)
    at bma.a(SourceFile:271)
    at bma.a(SourceFile:220)
    at bao.a(SourceFile:1694)
    at bao.a(SourceFile:1652)
    at bjb.a(SourceFile:125)
    at hd.a(SourceFile:70)
    at hd.a(SourceFile:13)
    at ej.a(SourceFile:174)
    at bao.p(SourceFile:1585)
    at bao.ak(SourceFile:774)
    at bao.f(SourceFile:728)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:148)
```

Comment: Does it give you an error message when it crashes? What are the versions of OS X, Java and Minecraft you have installed?

Comment: OS X 10.9.4 and Minecraft 1.7.10

Comment: You are running Minecraft under Java 6 not Java 8

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, Minecraft is hard coded to use Java 1.6 (or it might have been hard coded to only use Apple Java, can't 100% recall).

The way I have combatted this for some time is to launch Minecraft from Terminal.app using:

```
java -jar /Applications/Minecraft.app/Contents/Resources/Java/Bootstrap.jar
```

I think I recall Minecraft developer Dinnerbone suggesting that Minecraft 1.9 would not pose restrictions on Java version.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you could try.

Minecraft saves a log file in "~/Library/Application\ Support/minecraft/logs/". The most recent one might give more of a clue why Minecraft is crashing.

You could also try renaming that "~/Library/Application\ Support/minecraft" folder temporarily. If Minecraft successfully launches new games when that folder is hidden then it suggests one of the assets or settings files is causing the crashes rather than the game itself.

If that does work, then copying the contents of the "saves" folder into the new "minecraft" folder it's created should make any save games you have available. I just tried that myself and after logging in, and I was able to access my games okay.