# Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

Tags: macos, java

When I play Minecraft, usually on servers, my game constantly crashes, and the reason for this is: 'Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again!'

I am running on OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.5

I am running on Minecraft 1.8

I have contacted Minecraft support, and they didn't help me at all, but I soon noticed that Java was the issue.

I know that typing ulimit -c unlimited would be a temporary fix until the next time I run the game, but is there a way that I could make a permanent fix. I'm looking to fix my crashing issue. I'm looking for any clue that may help fix this issue.

[image: Minecraft Crash Report]

Comment: @KrunchyPlayz The crashes aren't caused by the core dumps. A Core Dump is the system collecting information AFTER a crash has happened. So developers can try to diagnose the cause of the crash. Very basically it's just writing everything that the application has in memory into a file. Java is just telling you that a crash happened and it can't collect data to help developers diagnose the fault.

Comment: Which version of Java do you have installed? And what model of Mac are you running this on? And is there a reason why you haven't upgraded to 10.11.6?

Comment: I have the iMac (27-inch, Late 2012) and I haven't upgraded to 10.11.6 b/c I just didn't have the chance.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the entire crash report: https://gyazo.com/b8c8ef90ad9946620daa4ba2f89f5554 https://gyazo.com/faef2e599fc0539941ae1df96b9c9489

Comment: Are you sure you're using the standalone launcher?

Answer (score 1):

First of all the crashes aren't caused by the core dumps. Very basically a core dump is just the system dumping all the data that an application has in memory into a file AFTER an application has crashed. To help developers try to diagnose the cause of a crash. The error "`Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again`" is just telling you that it wasn't able to gather this data.

The actual crash in this case appears to have been caused by one of the mods you have installed. The important part of the crash report is these first few lines...

```
Description: WDL mod: exception in onWorldRemoveEntityFromWorld event

java.lang.null.NullPointerException: WDL mod: exception in onWorldRemoveEntityFromWorld event
                    at wdl.WDLHooks.onWorldRemoveEntityFromWorld(WDLHooks.java:153)
                    at wdl.litemod.LiteModWDL.worldClientRemoveEntityFromWorld(LiteModWDL.java:104)
                    at com.mumfrey.liteloader.core.event.EventProxy.$event0000d(EventProxy.java:224)
```

Unfortunately there isn't enough information here to tell us which mod.

First thing I'd recommend is making sure you have Minecraft and all your mods up to date. If that doesn't solve the problem, then I'd recommend removing each mod one by one and playing a bit each time. Then when the crashes stop you know which mod was the cause. Process of elimination.

Comment: I would also check that Minecraft and the mod work under Java 8 earlier versions did not http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142316/minecraft-crashing-on-mac-os-with-java-8-any-fixes

Comment: Seems like it is the World Downloader Mod, Am I right?

Comment: @KrunchyPlayz That is where the exception happened. It's a good place to start. Out of curiosity more than anything else, is there a reason you're running an old version of Minecraft? You seem to be running 1.8 from Sept 2014 while the current version is 1.10.2. Even upgrading to the latest version of the 1.8 branch, 1.8.9, might solve some of the crashes.

Comment: Yes, the server runs on 1.8

Comment: Does that help?

Comment: Can I receive more assistance?

Comment: @KrunchyPlayz Did you try updating Minecraft to 1.8.9? Did you try the process of elimination I suggested above to determine which mod is causing the crashes?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem in java runtime version, I made the necessary update from https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572?locale=en_US And start the Android SDK successfully